# How do I sort a file based on both letters and numbers?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sort, file-sorting

A file with this content:

```
abc[0]
abc[100]
abc[101]
.
.
abc[127]
abc[19]
abc[1]
.  
. 
abc[9]   
xyz[0]  
xyz[100]  
xyz[101]  
.
.
xyz[127]
xyz[19]
xyz[1]
.
.
xyz[9]
```

I want to retain the alphabetical order but order according to the content in the brackets numerically.

```
abc[0]
abc[1]
abc[2]
.
.
abc[127]
xyz[0]
xyz[1]
xyz[2]
.
.
xyz[127]
```

Answer (score 5):

GNU sort's `--version-sort` should do that for you:

```
sort --version-sort file
```

Otherwise, use `[` as the separator and sort by the first field and then numerically by the second:

```
sort -t'[' -k1,1 -k2n file
```